# JMeter Assertions

Tags: user-interface, jmeter

Is there a way to use the icons in the tree to view response assertion failures in JMeter?  Maybe turning the icons red?  Or some other way to quickly see if there are any errors?  It's a pain to click every View Results Tree node to check for errors.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the icons turn red when a error occurs.
the only reason it wouldn't is because you've checked "ignore Status" in a response assertion, that occurs after your other checks. If you use ignore status,  make it the first assertion in your list.

Comment: your answer is truncated?

Comment: Sorry orig post was truncated, whoops :)

Comment: vote up cause your response.  Welcome to SO. :)  Please read the tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Use [Assertion Results](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#Assertion_Results) Listener and check Log/Display Only Errors checkbox

Answer (score 1):

If a sample fails an assertion, the icon turns red automatically.

Comment: BlackGaff, the icon in the Test Plan does not turn red. The one in the Result Tree does. Changing the one in Test Plan would be more useful.

Comment: @luis are you the OP? If so can you flag to have your accounts merged?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Result Tree Listener.So if any sample fails that particular sample turns red.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

It simple the color of assertion will be red only if that fail.
    **Other option** is stop the test when Assertion fail.
    i.e. check the **Stop Thread** option in Thread group